Trumpet: I am having issues using my first valve
I have tried oiling it, but it does not work. With a lot of force, I can screw in the valve, but air still cannot flow through the instrument. My first valve looks the same as my 2nd and 3rd (which work fine), and if I remove the first valve, air can flow again. My 1st valve casing has no visible dents, and I cannot feel any using my finger. It feels the same as the other valve casings. If I unscrew the bottom cap, to look at the piston moving up and down, I can see that I can press down the valve, but it gets stuck at the bottom of the valve casing, and I have to push it back up.

Have you checked that your valve is in fact oriented correctly? It is possible to insert a valve rotated by 180 degrees, causing it to obviously not work properly and block the airways.

Is this trumpet new to you? Have you ever got it to work before? If you've just acquired it and/or this is the first time you've tried using it, maybe it has values 223 or 323 instead of 123, like maybe someone at a used shop put it together wrong, or if it's new the factory messed up.

I just thought - if you've forced the valve piston into the casing then when you remove it you'll be able to see where the tight fit is; most of the valve piston will be matt/brushed surface, and the bit that's binding will have been polished smooth by the inside of the valve casing. Remember that valve pistons are hollow tubes with the airway tubes hard soldered in - doesn't take much to deform them - forcing them into the valve casing certainly could do it.

The clearance between a trumpet piston and the barrel that contains it are pretty tight. A hair in your valve may well stop it moving freely - we're talking a few thousandsths of an inch.
Which means that if your trumpet has had a knock or drop and suffered a tiny deformation or dent in the valve casing big enough to stop the valve moving freely that damage would be undetectable visually. So it might be your instrument is damaged and needs a visit to the repair shop.
But supposing your instrument is undamaged, the way to check whether all your valves are in the correct casings is as follows (assuming they're not numbered - do check - there might be an engraved digit on the valve piston itself, or engraved dots on the bottom. Inspect thoroughly!)
Each valve piston needs to be the correct valve for the casing and it needs to be correctly aligned (there are often two orientations for a valve, or just one, depending on what type of valve guide your instrument uses).

Remove all the valves from the instrument.
You'll see that the mouthpipe joins the third valve casing (the casing furthest from the mouthpiece). So take one of the valves and put it into the third valve casing and turn it until the valve guide clicks into the machined slot inside the valve casing.
Blow down the mouthpipe. If it's the correct piston and correctly aligned then the air will be correctly routed whether the valve is up or down.
If the air works when the valve is up but not when it's down (or vice versa), it could be it's the correct valve but 180 degrees misaligned. So lift the valve slightly and turn it until it clicks in the other orientation.
Repeat step 3.
If the air still doesn't work, try a different valve piston in the third casing.
When you're confident you've got the right valve in the right orientation in the third casing, leave the third valve piston where it is and repeat the above process for the second casing.

Once you've got the second valve correct you only have to get the alignment of the first piston correct and all the valve pistons are correctly installed.

"With a lot of force, I can screw in the valve"   For a start, that worries me!  Every time you force it, you're doing more damage.   Don't force it!
You seem to be describing two problems.  The valve doesn't move freely, but when it IS in position, air still doesn't flow. (Well, it's not really about air FLOW, but we'll let that pass.)
A valve can be in the wrong hole, or it can be in the right one but rotated incorrectly.  There will be some sort of keying mechanism that ensures it's rotated to the right alignment.   Investigate this.   You may be trying to force it down with the key not lined up with its slot.
You say it 'blows' when the first valve is removed.  So the other two are probably in their correct housings, and correctly rotated.   But if you want to check, take all three valves out.  Look at the tubing path from the mouthpiece.  The first valve it encounters is number three.  So make sure the valve in there lets air through when both up and down.  Then add a valve in the second position, do the same.   The one you've got left must be correct as valve one!

The valves may have been mixed up. First, take off the middle valve tube. Then you can ascertain, just by looking, if the holes line up when the valve is pressed. If not, there are two others which could fit, and do the job properly.
When you've established that the middle valve is the correct one, there's a 50:50 with the other two - you won't be able to see what's happening, but you'll be able to hear which is which.

Thank you, I was able to find that the 2nd and 3rd valve are working just fine. Also, now the first valve springs back up when pushed, however, it only comes up halfway, so I have to pull it back up. When the valve is down, air is fully blocked, and when the valve comes halfway back up, or fully up, the air is restricted in some way.

DO NOT FORCE the valve! There should be a keyway on it, which fits in the 'socket'. Look at the aspect of the holes, once you've established it is the correct one, and also look for the keyway. By now, I'm afraid, the valve or socket may be damaged beyond repair, so a trip to a brass repairer could well be in order.
